# What is the proper use of Leibniz notation for one-sided derivatives?

Tags: derivatives, notation

The only notation I've seen has been restricted to either Lagrange's prime notation or Euler's $D$. Here are some of the variants:
$$f'(a^+):=\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
$$D_+f(x):=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Is there a standard notation for the right- and left-handed derivatives using $\dfrac{df}{dx}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a standard way to show it

$${{df} \over {dx}}|_{x=x^{\pm}_0}$$

Comment: Nonstandard giving a standard way. Sounds funny! +1

Comment: I had a feeling this was it, but I thought the superscript on $x_0$ seemed a bit awkward at first. Thanks for the input!